# changing intervals in X and Y axis in high chart (line chart)

Tags: highcharts

I have a table with following data

trdate                                  price (Rs)

Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:43 AM   14.00
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:44 AM   14.00
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:44 AM   14.00
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:44 AM   14.00
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:45 AM   14.00
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:45 AM   14.10
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:45 AM   14.10
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:47 AM   14.20
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:47 AM   14.20
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:47 AM   14.20
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:47 AM   14.20
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:47 AM   14.20
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:48 AM   14.20
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:48 AM   14.30
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:48 AM   14.30
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:48 AM   14.30
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:48 AM   14.30
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:48 AM   14.30
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:48 AM   14.30
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:49 AM   14.30
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:49 AM   14.30
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:49 AM   14.30
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:49 AM   14.30
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:49 AM   14.30
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:51 AM   14.20
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:52 AM   14.20
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:52 AM   14.20
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:52 AM   14.20
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:52 AM   14.20
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:52 AM   14.20
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:52 AM   14.20
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:53 AM   14.20
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:53 AM   14.20
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:53 AM   14.20
Wednesday, November 7, 2012  09:53 AM   14.10

I want to show this data in a line chart with price in the Y axis and Time on the X axis, I need to know how to change the intervals in X and Y axis in Highcharts according to my requirement. This is a price movement of a stock over a period. the code I'm currently using for this is as below, but it generates a straight line only

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts expects dates to be Javascript Date numbers (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC). If the following string `Wednesday, November 7, 2012 09:43 AM 14.00` is what you have in your database you will first need to parse it to a number.

Ex:

```
Date.UTC(2012, 10, 7, 9, 43); 
// will output the number 1357551780000
```